# getting control error when using not fact(something) in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have this fact:

```
test(something).
```

When I write:

```
test(X).
```

the answer is: X = something, but when I write:

```
not test(X).
```

I get:

'Error 21 : Control Error
! Goal     : not .........................'

Why ? 
I thought the answer should be 'no'.

When I implement not by myself:

```
 not(P):-
   P,!,fail
   ;
   true.
```

and write: 
    not(test(X)).

Prolog does answer 'no'.

Comment: not is `\+(...)`. You may also use `not(...)`

Answer (score 1):

The same happens if you run `alpha test(X).`

The `not` you are looking for is a unary predicate taking the goal to be proven:

https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=not/1

So you have to write `not(test(X))`. But you shouldn't; use `\+ test(X)` instead.

What does the query `alpha test(X).` mean? I am not sure...